# Sign a binary unsigned for appstore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I developed an iPhone application for a client.
He wants me to pass the unsigned binary and sign and submit itself in itunes connect.
Is that possible? there is no risk he sees the code?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

He could potentially give you distribution certificates (or access to the iOS Dev portal) depending on your relationship.